# using a linkbutton to redirect to resetpassword page with forms authentication

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I have this in my web.config

```
<authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms name="Login" loginUrl="Login.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" protection="All" path="/" timeout="20" requireSSL="false" defaultUrl="Main.aspx" />
    </authentication>
```

Now on my login-page I have a linkbutton to reset the password:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnForgotPassword" runat="server">Forgot password</asp:LinkButton>
```

In my codebehind i do the following:

```
Protected Sub ResetPassword(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnForgotPassword.Click
    Response.Redirect("ResetPassword.aspx")
End Sub
```

but when I click the linkbutton, I'm redirected to my original loginpage, i guess due to the authentication mode.
How can i change it, so I do get redirected to my resetpassword-page?

Below is part of my config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `<location>` entry in web.config to allow all users access to the `ResetPassword.aspx` page:

```
<location path="ResetPassword.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>        
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: Where should I add it in my config?
I've added it but it still doesn't work. So I guess I'm setting in the wrong place.

Comment: Just after your `<system.web>` completes, i.e. after `</system.web>` tag

Comment: Even putting it in the location you said, it doesn't work

Comment: make sure your path is correct, `<location path="ResetPassword.aspx">`  If you have `ResetPassword.aspx` under some folder then you need to provide path accordingly.

Comment: As far as I can see, everything is correct. I'm not using a folder or anything.

Comment: Could the problem be, that I redirect to a page which is based on a master-page? When I redirect to a simple htm-page, it works

Comment: That was indeed the problem. i removed the masterpage and now it works.

Comment: Great that you discovered the issue and resolved it.